# Light-Weight Database System for C++

Tags: c++, database

I need to use light-weight database because i have limited resource for application.

So i'm searching a light-weight database which i can use with C++, which is easy to manage, fast to retrieve data and  uses up limited amount of resource.

I  have found SqlLite in the internet. But before i start to implement my project, i want to get your recommendation on this topic.

Any help  will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've already find your best option in my opinion: [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

You could technically use something even lighter like plain old file system with random file access. But you will miss two key points:

1. Easy creation of indexes on your data
2. An awesome language to get and manipulate data: SQL

SQLite will only add a couple of kilobytes to your executable and it's pretty lightweight. Plus, its API is relatively easy to use.

Comment: do you know a good C++ interface ? I only ever saw the C-ish one.

Comment: If I were you I would just use the C interface. You can perfectly do that from C++. If you absolutely want and need a C++ interface, you can take a look at SQLite++: http://sqlitepp.berlios.de/

Answer (score 5):

SQLite is definitely one of the best options, specially if you need proper SQL support. For smaller things, [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) could also be worth of consider.

Comment: If Bekeley DB is in play (i.e. you only require key-value data-stores) - any of the many NoSQL data stores are available to you(the OP) - Tokyo Cabinet/Tokyo Tyrant, Voldemort, Cassandra, Riak, memcached(it's a cache not a DB though), etc. This [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL_(concept)) lists many, if not all of them. You can take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

Both SQLite and BerkleyDB are good, but they are still overcomplicated for really simple tasks. If your "database" consists of two tables of 1000 entries each, nothing beats mundane binary file and search optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

[Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) with [IBPP](http://www.ibpp.org/) drivers can do the job

> The embedded version is an amazing
>   variation of the server. It is a fully
>   featured Firebird server packed in
>   just a few files. It is very easy to
>   deploy, since there is no need to
>   install the server